# Proving by pigeonhole principle that a duocolored $3\times9$ rectangle will always contain subrectangles whose corners are the same color.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, coloring

Lets say each square of a $3\times9$ rectangular board is colored either blue or red. How can I prove mathematically that for any such coloring, the board will always contain a subrectangle (paralell to the original one) whose four corners are the same color?

I have a feeling it has something to do with $3^2 = 9$, therefore a $3\times9$ rectangle would have this be true where a 3x6 triangle would not because $3^2 \neq 6$. I'm not sure if that's even remotely correct - just a hunch.

I'm also thinking about the fact that each of the $27$ squares is a rectangle itself, therefore, you would always end up with one of those squares having each of its four corners are the same color.

I know this involves the pigeonhole principle, but I'm just not sure how to "prove" it. Any tips in the right direction?

Comment: This is a neat one, which uses the PP twice. And corindo beat me to it. (I was only going to provide a hint.) The next level would be coloring squares red, white, or blue, and coloring each of the squares of a $4\times 17$ rectangle with one of these three colors; now prove that there is a rectangle all of whose corners have the same color. ($k$ colors: $(k+1)\times (2^{k+1}+1)$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are $9$ columns and $3$ rows of duo-colored squares. For each column of $3$ squares there are $2^3=8$ possible combinations. So by the pigeonhole principle there must be $2$ columns that have the same combination. And for each of these $2$ columns, there must be two squares that have the same color. So you can find the required rectangle now.

---

**EDIT**:

I think the minimal number of columns is $7$. Each column must contain two squares of the same color. Suppose the two colors are R and B, then the possible positions are:

$$ \mbox{RR*,R*R,*RR,BB*，B*B,*BB} $$

where the * means any color.

So if there are more than $6$(greater than or equal to $7$) colomuns then one of the above $6$ positions must repeat and then create a rectangle with same color.

And a $6$-column counter-example is obvious from the discussion above:

$$\begin{matrix}
\mathrm{\color{Red}R} & \mathrm{\color{Blue}B} & \mathrm{\color{Blue}B} & \mathrm{\color{Red}R} & \mathrm{\color{Red}R} & \mathrm{\color{Blue}B} \\
\mathrm{\color{Blue}B} & \mathrm{\color{Red}R} & \mathrm{\color{Blue}B} & \mathrm{\color{Red}R} & \mathrm{\color{Blue}B} & \mathrm{\color{Red}R} \\
\mathrm{\color{Blue}B} & \mathrm{\color{Blue}B} & \mathrm{\color{Red}R} & \mathrm{\color{Blue}B} & \mathrm{\color{Red}R} & \mathrm{\color{Red}R} 
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Ah, but is the 9 minimal? **EDIT:** (No, it isn't. If you color a $3\times8$ rectangle with two colors, it can be proven that there is a rectangle, all of whose corners have the same color.)

Comment: I don't think $9$ is minimal. It can be proven that $7$ is sufficient. Just first notice that each column must contain 2 squares of the same color. And there are $2\times 3 = 6$ possible positions for the "co-colored" squares of each column, so by pigeonhole principle, in $7$ columns there must be $2$ where the "co-colored" squares have the same position and same color.

Comment: I saw that 8 was sufficient because either you have duplicate columns (and the argument for $3\times9$ goes through), or every column is colored differently. But then you have a column colored RRB and one colored RRR, and those two columns form a "desired" rectangle. ... So what about 6?

Comment: well 4: rgg, grg, ggr, rrr ( i think - it's still early!)

Comment: I agree on the $3\times 4$ case; I got rrb;rbr;brr;bbb, which doesn't have a "desired" rectangle. I'm thinking that $3\times5$ will ... However, my proof doesn't look right, on second thought.

Comment: Here's a $3\times5$ counterexample: rrb; rbr; brr; bbr; brb. Again, assuming that I haven't missed anything. (It's getting late here as well, and I need to sign off.) There's probably a $3\times6$ counterexample as well.

Comment: each row must be unique, so there are only 8C7 possibilities with 7 columns

Comment: For seven, there are only six possible columns which do not contain three the same. These make up the arrangement for six. If there are two columns the same then you get a rectangle. If all the columns are different, you must have a column all the same, say a column all red. Then the all other columns can contain at most one red. There are four possible arrangements with at most one red, and six slots to fill.

Comment: I took the liberty of coloring the rectangle at the end, though you can revert it if you want.

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger columbus: Thanks! Much nicer now.